# Bound on recursive sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers satisfying $A_1=A_2=1$ and the recursion relationship
$$
A_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-2}{j-1} A_j A_{n-j}.
$$
Calculating the first few terms, I believe this corresponds to the sequence https://oeis.org/A007558.  There I find an asymptotic formula
$$
A_n \sim c d^n n! n.
$$
I am curious whether there is a simple argument showing simply that
$$
A_n \leq C^n n^n
$$
for some $C$.